# Discordpy embed not getting sent

Tags: python, discord

```
...on_message():
channel = message.channel

embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Ok {member_name}**", description=f"Command cancelled. You might get better results with a second read.\n\nOr please see {info_chan} under 'Updating Stats' for other update options.", color=0xcc79a7)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

this is not working for some reason. I have same code in other on_message if statements which work perfectly

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help ya out!

It seems your on_message isn't being sent because you forgot to add the parameters when creating your event (you could have this but didnt show it)! Also, that color doesn't exist, so I would double check your hex. Here's how you can solve your issue:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message): # I defined my message
    channel = message.channel

    embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = f"Okay {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", 
# I did this only so that way if the event gets called in a private channel ^, 
# you wont get an error (message.author returns abc.User if it's in a private channel.) 
                    description = f"Command cancelled. You might get better results with a second read.\n\nOr please see {info_chan} under 'Updating Stats' for other update options.",
                    color = CC79A7) # did a pink for you
    
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

You can check out the discord.py docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.colour